# Can't detect wifi networks until put to sleep

Tags: networking, wireless, 17.10

I have a laptop that has a weird behaviour when it comes to wifi conectivity: When it boots up, it detects the Wifi card, but when I list the available networks to connect on it just shows an empty list (and the icon of that it's refreshing)

This is, until I put the system into sleep. When I set it back on, then the whole list of network appears, I can connect to them and internet works perfectly. It's not a HW issue because when I had windows in this laptop this didn't happen, and I'm not moving the screen when putting it to sleep (I know this could be relevant since wifi antennas are often on the screen and it may open/close the contact with the adapter.

I've taken a look on possible solutions, but I'm lost on what to do. I updated the drivers but that didn't solve the issue.

Here is some commands I used to get any info:

```
$ sudo rfkill list
8: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
9: phy4: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
[After sleep/awake there are no changes]

$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:4
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 38:a2:8c:dd:90:fb
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8xxxu driverversion=4.13.0-17-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
[After sleep/awake nothing changes]

$ ifconfig -a
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 412  bytes 25856 (25.8 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 412  bytes 25856 (25.8 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 38:a2:8c:dd:90:fb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
[After sleep/awake nothing changes]

$ ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 38:a2:8c:dd:90:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[After sleep/awake nothing changes]

$ dmesg | grep 1-4
[    3.832315] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    3.972863] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=b720
[    3.972866] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    3.972868] usb 1-4: Product: 802.11n WLAN Adapter
[    3.972870] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Realtek
[    3.972871] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
[    8.098010] usb 1-4: This Realtek USB WiFi dongle (0x0bda:0xb720) is untested!
[    8.098014] usb 1-4: Please report results to Jes.Sorensen@gmail.com
[    8.252101] usb 1-4: Vendor: Realtek
[    8.252104] usb 1-4: Product: 802.11n WLAN Adapter
[    8.252106] usb 1-4: rtl8723bu_parse_efuse: dumping efuse (0x200 bytes):
(large dump here)
[    8.252226] usb 1-4: RTL8723BU rev E (SMIC) 1T1R, TX queues 3, WiFi=1, BT=1, GPS=0, HI PA=0
[    8.252229] usb 1-4: RTL8723BU MAC: 38:a2:8c:dd:90:fb
[    8.252231] usb 1-4: rtl8xxxu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723bu_nic.bin
[    8.254976] usb 1-4: Firmware revision 35.0 (signature 0x5301)
##### After sleep/awake #####
[  509.983513] usb 1-4: disconnecting
[  509.983519] usb 1-4: Device still attached, trying to reset
[  510.105432] usb 1-4: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  513.226029] usb 1-4: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  513.367975] usb 1-4:1.0: rebind failed: -517
[  513.368008] usb 1-4:1.2: rebind failed: -517
[  515.051381] usb 1-4: This Realtek USB WiFi dongle (0x0bda:0xb720) is untested!
[  515.051394] usb 1-4: Please report results to Jes.Sorensen@gmail.com
[  515.112651] usb 1-4: Vendor: Realtek
[  515.112656] usb 1-4: Product: 802.11n WLAN Adapter
[  515.112659] usb 1-4: rtl8723bu_parse_efuse: dumping efuse (0x200 bytes):
(large dump here)
[  515.112827] usb 1-4: RTL8723BU rev E (SMIC) 1T1R, TX queues 3, WiFi=1, BT=1, GPS=0, HI PA=0
[  515.112831] usb 1-4: RTL8723BU MAC: 38:a2:8c:dd:90:fb
[  515.112834] usb 1-4: rtl8xxxu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723bu_nic.bin
[  515.112863] usb 1-4: Firmware revision 35.0 (signature 0x5301)
[  517.457437] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  517.563643] usb 1-4: rtl8xxxu_active_to_lps: RX poll timed out (0x05f8)
[  517.581014] usb 1-4: rtl8723bu_active_to_emu: Disabling MAC timed out
[  517.581019] usb 1-4: disconnecting
[  522.113676] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  522.258117] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=b720
[  522.258122] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  522.258124] usb 1-4: Product: 802.11n WLAN Adapter
[  522.258126] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Realtek
[  522.258128] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
[  522.266921] usb 1-4: This Realtek USB WiFi dongle (0x0bda:0xb720) is untested!
[  522.266925] usb 1-4: Please report results to Jes.Sorensen@gmail.com
[  522.330063] usb 1-4: Vendor: Realtek
[  522.330066] usb 1-4: Product: 802.11n WLAN Adapter
[  522.330069] usb 1-4: rtl8723bu_parse_efuse: dumping efuse (0x200 bytes):
(large dump here)
[  522.330177] usb 1-4: RTL8723BU rev E (SMIC) 1T1R, TX queues 3, WiFi=1, BT=1, GPS=0, HI PA=0
[  522.330180] usb 1-4: RTL8723BU MAC: 38:a2:8c:dd:90:fb
[  522.330182] usb 1-4: rtl8xxxu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723bu_nic.bin
[  522.330205] usb 1-4: Firmware revision 35.0 (signature 0x5301)
[  525.618001] usb 1-4: rtl8xxxu_bss_info_changed: HT supported

$ dmesg | grep rtl
[    7.899970] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[    7.899976] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
[    7.910765] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin failed with error -2
[    7.910771] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[    8.252106] usb 1-4: rtl8723bu_parse_efuse: dumping efuse (0x200 bytes):
[    8.252231] usb 1-4: rtl8xxxu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723bu_nic.bin
[    9.230698] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8xxxu
##### After sleep/awake #####
[  515.068531] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[  515.068535] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
[  515.068560] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin failed with error -2
[  515.068563] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[  515.112659] usb 1-4: rtl8723bu_parse_efuse: dumping efuse (0x200 bytes):
[  515.112834] usb 1-4: rtl8xxxu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723bu_nic.bin
[  517.563643] usb 1-4: rtl8xxxu_active_to_lps: RX poll timed out (0x05f8)
[  517.581014] usb 1-4: rtl8723bu_active_to_emu: Disabling MAC timed out
[  522.278986] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[  522.278991] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
[  522.279023] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin failed with error -2
[  522.279026] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[  522.330069] usb 1-4: rtl8723bu_parse_efuse: dumping efuse (0x200 bytes):
[  522.330182] usb 1-4: rtl8xxxu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723bu_nic.bin
[  525.618001] usb 1-4: rtl8xxxu_bss_info_changed: HT supported
```

So on the `dmesg` logs it's the only place where I can find differences... but still I'm not sure what's going on.

Can anyone help me fix this so I don't have to put to sleep, just to awake again my laptop right after booting it up?

Note: Although `dmesg` shows this adapter as an usb dongle, it is not. It's integrated inside the laptop.

**EDIT 1**

```
$ lsmod | grep rtl
rtl8xxxu              126976  0
mac80211              778240  1 rtl8xxxu
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             540672  33 btrtl,hci_uart,btintel,btqca,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb
[After sleep/awake there are no changes]

$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:069e Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b720 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[After sleep/awake]
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:069e Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:b720 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**EDIT 2**

```
$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf 
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Comment: We are well and truly confused! May we see: `lsmod | grep rtl` and also: `lsusb` Please edit your question to add the results.

Comment: @chili555 I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

> Although dmesg shows this adapter as an usb dongle, it is not. It's
>   integrated inside the laptop.

I suspect it is attached to an internal USB bus on the motherboard. It is a bit unusual but it has been seen before.

You will probably need a change to Network Manager:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Add a new section as follows:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

After making these changes, reboot and let us hear the result.

Comment: I already had this section in `NetworkManager.conf`, so I haven't add it (I guess that if it's already there I shouldn't add it again). I updated my question with the current value of that file